# Edit text - getText() returning wrong value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a questionnaire, so I have a few inputs in a recycler view, but whenever I try to use `getText().toString()`, it returns the wrong value.

I'm trying to read the values from an `onClickListener` which is declared in `onBindViewHolder` :

```
        holder.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < questions.size() - 1; i++)
            {
                Question current = questions.get(i);
                boolean isAnswered = true;
                Log.d("Tag type", current.type);

                switch (current.type)
                {
                    case "Number":
                        current.answer = holder.edtNum.getText().toString();
                        break;

                    case "Text":
                        current.answer = holder.edtText.getText().toString();
                        break;
                }

                if (answer.isEmpty())
                    isAnswered = false;

                current.isAnswered = isAnswered;
                questions.set(i, current);
                Log.d("Answer Tag", current.answer);
            }
            holder.checkAnswers();
        }
    });
```

But `Log.d("Tag type", current.type);` returns the wrong value.

The edit texts are declared in the ViewHolder constructor:

```
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tViewQuestion);
        
        btnYes = view.findViewById(R.id.btnQYes);
        btnNo = view.findViewById(R.id.btnQNo);
        edtNum = view.findViewById(R.id.edtQNum);
        spinRange = view.findViewById(R.id.spinQRange);
        edtText = view.findViewById(R.id.edtQText);
        spinMulti = view.findViewById(R.id.spinQMulti);
        btnSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.btnQSubmit);
    }
```

I know similar questions have been asked previously, but none of those answers are working for me, please help.

Comment: have you tried adding a cast to your EditText? like `edtNum = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtQNum);`

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: What is this "wrong value"?

Comment: It returns the default value, like 'Name' instead of the value I've entered